# React - How to show relative div when mouse hover on a html tag?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Below is my code...

```
<ul className="no-style board__list">
   {Object.keys(today.books).map(function(id) {
       var refBook = today.books[id][0];                                            
          return (
            <li key={refBook._id} className="board__list-item">
                <div className="container flexrow">
                      <div className="flexrow__fit-2">{refBook.book_no}</div>
                      <div className="flexrow__org">
                         <span className="board__icon-wrap">
                           {refBook.memo
                               ? (<i className="fa fa-flag" style={{color:"#F9AB9F"}}></i>)
                               : null
                           }
                        </span>
                           {refBooking.memo
                               ? (<div  className="memo_dialog">{refBook.memo}</div>)
                               : null
                           }
                     </div>
                </div>
           </li>
        );
    })}
</ul>
```

I have a object books array and I create a fa-flag icon for each book.
What I want is to show different memo dialog when mouse hover on each flag icon.

I know how to do it with query but how can I do this in react way not using jquery?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what are you trying to achieve but this example might be useful for you

```
class Book extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.handleOver = this.handleOver.bind(this);
  }
  handleOver(name){
    this.props.over(this.props.name)
  }
  render(){
    return <div onMouseOver={this.handleOver}>{this.props.name}</div>
  }
}

class BookList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.mouseOver = this.mouseOver.bind(this);
    this.state = {
        books: ['hello', 'amazing', 'world'],
      memo: ''
    }
  }
  mouseOver(name){
    this.setState({memo: name})
  }
  render(){
    const bookList = this.state.books.map((book, index)=>{
        return <Book key={index} name={book} over={this.mouseOver}/>
    });
    return <div>
        {bookList}
      <hr/>
      <div>{this.state.memo}</div>
    </div>
  }
}

React.render(<BookList />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

Also [`fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/jwm6k66c/897/) example.

I hope it will help you. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use `isHovered` state variable, to store `hover` state.

We are displaying some component(in your case it would be dialog box), if `isHovered` is `true` and hide it when this variable is `false`.

When we will hover on link element, we will trigger `handleEnter` function to set `isHovered` variable to `true`.

Similarly, when we are moving cursor out of link element, we are triggering `handleLeave` function to set `isHovered` variable to `false`.

Example:

```
class Test extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      isHovered: false,
    };
  }

  handleEnter() {
    this.setState({
      isHovered: true 
    });
  }

  handleLeave() {
    this.setState({
      isHovered: false 
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <a
          onMouseEnter={this.handleEnter.bind(this)}
          onMouseLeave={this.handleLeave.bind(this)}
        >Link</a>
        {this.state.isHovered ? (
          <div className="box">A component</div>
        ) : (
          <div />
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Also, you can see [demo](http://codepen.io/1ven/pen/PzxbzE?editors=0010) at CodePen.